# How to set up port forwarding for torrenting with WireGuard VPN on VPS?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, port-forwarding, wireguard

I have a VPS (Outside my home network) running a WireGuard VPN (PiVPN + Pi-hole+ Unbound), and I'm trying to set up port forwarding for improved torrenting performance (like what services such as ProtonVPN and AirVPN provide). My Windows 10 computer is the client, and it's behind a router.

I've already configured port forwarding on my router, but I'm struggling to get it working correctly on my VPS. Can someone please provide a step-by-step guide on how to set up port forwarding on my VPS for this purpose?

So far I've tried the following with no luck

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s6 -p tcp --dport 32554 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.221.178.2

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 32554 -d 10.221.178.2 -j MASQUERADE
```

Additional Info:

```
OS and Network info:
OS running on VPS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
OS running on PC: WIndows 10
VPS public ip: 1.2.3.4
WireGuard interface: wg0
IPv4 address for wg0: 10.221.178.1
Network adapter on VPS: enp0s6
IPv4 address for enp0s6: 10.0.0.18
Port used for incoming connections on qbittorrent: 32554

Iptables rules on server: https://rentry.co/pniz3pkn

Wireguard Config:
::::  Server configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = server_priv
Address = 10.221.178.1/24,fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::1/64
MTU = 1420
ListenPort = 51820
### begin zephyrus-m ###
[Peer]
PublicKey = zephyrus-m_pub
PresharedKey = zephyrus-m_psk
AllowedIPs = 10.221.178.2/32,fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::2/128
### end zephyrus-m ###
=============================================
::::  Client configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = zephyrus-m_priv
Address = 10.221.178.2/24,fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::2/64
DNS = 10.221.178.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_pub
PresharedKey = zephyrus-m_psk
Endpoint = REDACTED:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
```